# Reloading page without browser knowing

Tags: javascript, html, browser, webbrowser-control

I currently am building a website that fetchs data from MySQL with php and then displays it. On one of the pages I use a form to submit data and then I reload the page to display it. It does it's job fine and works exactly as I want the only problem is when a user presses the browser back button it goes through all previously submitted data instead of just going back to the page it came from. Is there a way to reload a page without the browser storing it or is there a way to make the browser go back to the previous page instead of history.
NOTE: I am aware of Ajax and how to use it to not reload the page at all but I wanted to see if there was a way to do it without redesigning my whole page with a seemingly small problem.

Comment: Have a look at html5 history.pushState it may help with your issue (depending on what browser version you are supporting) https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `history.replaceState` in HTML5.

Another possibility appears to be

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  window.history.go(-1);
};
```

although I have not tried this myself.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API and  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate